# (Solved) Selenium: Get amount of images from Website (maximum is 120)

Tags: python, selenium

I tried to get the amount of Images in a specific website (there are more than 120), but i always get 
120 as result even if i add one or delete one.
Images on this Website are represented by: id = "item-[specific number of Image]" so i wanted to search for every image by getting every element with this "item-" part in its ID.

Tried it with another Website with 106 Pictures and it works fine.

Is there some sort of maximum it can store?
Or another way to get Images from a website via Selenium rather than searching by its xpath?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import *
images = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'item')]")
print(len(images))
```

Solved:
It was a problem of the loading time on this website after i did a scroll to the end of the page it worked as intended:

```
self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Comment: There is no such limit. Here you're counting how many elements contain the string 'item' in their id: this is not a generic count of images. You should be more specific if you need help.

Comment: okay, sorry for that. On this website every Image is presented with: id = "item-[specific number for every picture]", so i wanted to get the images by searching for every id that begins with "element". is there another way to search for Images on a Website rather than searching by my given xpath?